# javascript Date and python datetime object

Tags: javascript, python, datetime

In javascript console ,I tried this

```
d=new Date()
t=d.getTime()
```

When I printed t,it gave

```
>>1334855220112
```

As per documentation ,it must be `the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01`

In python ,I created a `datetime.datetime` object as

```
nowdtime=datetime.datetime.today()
print str(int(nowdtime.strftime("%s"))*1000)
```

This gave the result:

```
'1334855221000'
```

This value looks very close to the result I got from javascript console.

the value of nowdtime is

```
datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 19, 22, 37, 1, 866262)
```

My doubt is why `nowdtime.strftime("%s")` returns number of seconds since epoch?

If I give  `nowdtime.strftime("%H")` ,it will only return `22` which is the hour according to 24 hr clock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%s` must be some sort of platform specific (ie, not documented at http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime) directive:

> Additional directives may be supported on certain platforms, but only
>   the ones listed here have a meaning standardized by ANSI C.

Ie, Win7 Python 2.6.6 iPython console:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 19, 22, 37, 1, 866262)
d.strftime("%s") # gives: ''
```

I'm not sure if this answers your question, because I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: thanks for telling me about the platform specific issue..I was using linux..so didn't know whether it worked on windows.  Anyway ,`time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple()) * 1000` returns the expected milliseconds since epoch.

Comment: Yeah, I get your result on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use the time method from time module `time.time()` to get a float that indicates the time in seconds since epoch.